# Can't see how the compiler uses the classes he creates for my closures

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, reflector

I wrote this very basic programm to examine what the compiler is doing behind the scenes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var increase = Increase();
        Console.WriteLine(increase());
        Console.WriteLine(increase());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Func<int> Increase()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        return () => counter++;
    }
}
```

Now when I look at the code with Reflector I do see that the compiler generates a class for my closure like that:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1
{
    // Fields
    public int counter;

    // Methods
    public int <Increase>b__0()
    {
        return this.counter++;
    }
}
```

That's fine and I'm aware that he needs to do that to handle my closure. However, what I can't see is how he is actually using this class. I mean I should be able to find code that instantiates "<>c__DisplayClass1" somewhere, am I wrong?

**EDIT**

If I click on the increase method it looks like that:

```
private static Func<int> Increase()
{
    int counter = 0;
    return delegate {
        return counter++;
    };
}
```

Comment: could you post the rest of the compiled code? Especially your Main method.

Comment: @dowhilefor: The Main method would actually be pretty boring. It's just calling a method to get a delegate, invoking the delegate a couple of times and printing out the results, then calling `Console.ReadLine`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should find it in the `Increase` method, which I'd expect to have an implementation along these lines:

```
// Not actually valid C# code because of the names...
static Func<int> Increase()
{
    <>c__DisplayClass1 closure = new c__DisplayClass1();
    closure.counter = 0;
    return new Func<int>(closure.<Increase>b__0);
}
```

Reflector won't show you that code unless you turn off its optimization, but it should be there. Either turn off Reflector's optimization, or use ildasm.

Comment: I would expect it to look like that but it doesn't. Do I need to get a commercial version of reflector to see it?

Comment: Sorry for beeing dump but how do I turn of its optimization? I can't find it. I'm using Resharper 6.8.2.5 btw.

Comment: @Cristoph: Just turning off Reflector's optimization has usually worked for me (or setting the level down to .NET 1.1). Have you tried just looking at the IL instead?

Comment: @Cristoph: On the version I'm using, there's a dropdown just to the right of the language selection box. It *used* to be under a preference called Optimization.

Comment: In my version thats hidden in the options but it is there. And if I adjust it to .NET 1.0 I see how it is getting used. But just to get it right. Will the compiler generate different code when you target a different .NET version?

Comment: Or to make it clearer. When setting optimizing to .NET 2.0 or higher. Why does he create a <>c__DisplayClass1 but doesn't use it?

Comment: @Christoph: When you're changing Reflector settings, you're not changing what the *C# compiler* does - you're just changing what steps Reflector will try to take to show you something like the original C# code.

Comment: ah, ok. Got that! Thanks a lot!